# What regex should be used to avoid symbols before text in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

i have following variable. i only want to print yes if the variable has "imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory" not # or anything. What should insert in a regex for this kind of things.

```
  my $textfile = "# imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory
                    imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory
                  #imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory";
  my $textNeeded= "imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory"
```

THIS IS WHAT  i am using

```
  if ($textfile =~ m/$textNeeded/i) {
       print "yes working"

  }
```

note:- i am getting data from differnt text files so some text files might just have "#imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory". I want to avoid those

Comment: Be more specific of what you want to match, i.e. four words separated by `/`, or what?

Comment: Why not just check to see that the first character of the string is a letter, instead of using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the quite vague problem description, I think I have puzzled out what you mean. You mean you may have lines where the text is commented out with `#`, and you want to avoid matching those.

```
print "yes" if $textfile =~ /^\s*$textNeeded/im;
```

This will match any string inside `$textfile` which has a newline followed by optional whitespace followed by your string. The `/m` option makes the regex multiline, meaning that `^` and `$` match line endings represented by newlines inside a larger string.

You may wish to be wary of regex meta characters in your search string. If for example your search string is `foo[bar].txt`, those brackets will be interpreted as a character class instead. In which case you would use

```
/^\s*\Q$textNeeded\E/im
```

instead. The `\Q ... \E` will make the text inside match only literal characters.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply and sorry about not putting it in proper words

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create an Anchor to say you want a match if your target string appears at the BEGINNING of the line.  This uses the up-carat symbol:

if ($textfile =~ m/**^**$textNeeded/i) {
       print "yes working"

}

This wont report a match if you have spaces or tabs before your textNeeded string.

Comment: hey, I already tried this. this only works if your variable is like this ex    my $textfile="# imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory"; has this" but what if your variable contains both values one with  # and one without?

Answer (score 0):

To simply return the rows having no leading hash, something like this:

```
my $textfile = "# imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory
                    imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory
                  #imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory";

for (split /^/, $textfile) {
  print $_ if(m/^\s*[a-zA-Z].*/);
}
```

Returns:

```
                imoport/canada/campingplaces/tobermory
```